# why subsequent HTTP requests

Tags: node.js, rest, http, browser-sync

My JavaScript makes that ajax call which retrieves a JSON array.

I am trying simulate long running HTTP REST call request that takes longer to return the results.

The way I do it is delay writing anything to the response object on the server side until 5 minutes elapsed since the request landed. After that I set the status to 200 and write the response with the JSON ending the stream.

Putting a breakpoint on the serve side I realize that the request shows up second time but the browser's Network tab does not show another request being made.

It may not be relevant but I am using `browsersync` middlewars to serve this JSON and write the bytes and end the response in `setTimeout()`.

```
setTimeout(()=> {
    res.statusCode = 200;
    res.write(data);
    res.end();
});
```

**Question:**

Anyone has any explanation as to why this is happening ? And if there is a way to simulate this in another ways ?

Comment: Ire both req objects are exactly the same?

Comment: `Are both req objects same ?` The uri is same - it is coming from same browser.

Comment: Check if everything is the same

Comment: What should I look ? Object reference ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cases the browser should retry if connection is closed before response.  This is a link to the details => [HTTP spec  Client Behavior if Server Prematurely Closes Connection](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec8.html#sec8.2.4)

BTW it might help you use the chrome throttling options on the network section of dev tools (F12)

Comment: Connection is not closed because the Network tab shows Pending.

Comment: Connections are different.